# Rails Google Calendar API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oauth, google-calendar-api

First time trying to use the google calendar gem in my rails app. What I am hoping to do is Post to the google calendar API's 2 users or email addresses of some sort and then try to find a free/busy schedule for both emails.

One of the emails will be authenticated through oauth and the other emails calendar is normally visible to the user who has been authenticated.

Is this possible? Any advice or pointers in the right direction are greatly appreciated!

Tyler

Comment: You've tried the freebusy query with the api? https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/freebusy/query 

Of course this is possible, you just need to figure out the logic of efficiently scheduling based on freebusy. You could store booked times locally so you know not to even bother? You could build a script that checks every hour across a predetermined window (9-5?) etc. etc.

Comment: Thanks for this! I have made some progress in the fact I know what the requests are and tested them on google side, Now I just need to figure out how to put this in my application. New to ruby on rails and not sure how to prompt a user for input since the free busy times would be a range rather than a specific date.